# Strange date format behaviour , iOS

Tags: ios, date, format

I am trying to convert a date from this :

`2012-06-26 12:00:00 +0000`

to this :

```
Jun 26, 2012 12:00:00 AM
```

If i use this code , it works :

```
NSString *inputString = @"2012-06-25 12:00:00 +0000";

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z"];//input

    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:inputString];

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSString *outputString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"Output Date is: %@" , outputString);
```

and the date printed is correctly this : `Jun 26, 2012 12:00:00 AM`

However the thing gets really strange when i dont hardcode the date , but use a function to get it. The code :

```
    NSString *inputString2 = [self.selectedDate description]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",inputString2);

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z"];//input

    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:inputString2];

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSString *outputString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"Output Date is: %@" , outputString);
```

When i print in the beginning of the code the inpuString2 variable just to make sure that the date is correctly delivered by the function there i have this: `2012-06-25 12:00:00 +0000` which is the correct date. But now the output date is nil when printed!!

Any ideas?? how is this possible??

Comment: with the NSLog, also do something like if([inputString isEqualString:inputString2]) to be 100% the strings are identical. Maybe they seem similar but there's something wrong with the encoding or you have some white spaces.

Comment: If you NSlog the `date` right after `dateFromString:` is the date null?

Answer (score 3):

Its the date format string for formatter

You have

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss z"];
```

Try instead

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
```

Note: **HH** not hh and **Z** not z.

RE: the second formatter string - you could change that to

```
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
```

(but I thought you were just asking about the **nil**)

Comment: this line should be changed too?? [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];  with capital HH and A ??

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming `selectedDate` date is `NSDate`, instead of converting use the following

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
NSString *outputString = [formatter stringFromDate:self.selectedDate];
NSLog(@"Output Date is: %@" , outputString);
```

This may not answer your question, but it should give you correct date